# Java 3D code giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, awt, java-3d

I am trying to run the following Java 3D sample code. I am referring 3 jars and 1 dll folder. Their names are as follows :-

1. vecmath.jar
2. j3d-core-1.3.1.jar
3. j3dutils.jar
4. j3dcore-ogl.dll (I also tried referring a jar file instead of this dll file. The jar file is j3dcore-d3d_dll.jar).

I have also tried placing them on bin and lib folders of jdk and jre.

I have also added the path of the that j3dcore-ogl.dll file in the system environment variable named "Path". Later on I tried replacing it with the path of j3dcore-d3d_dll.jar file.

The code is as follows :-

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.media.j3d.AmbientLight;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class InteractiveAnimation extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Button go = new Button("Go");

  private TransformGroup objTrans;

  private Transform3D trans = new Transform3D();

  private float height = 0.0f;

  private float sign = 1.0f; // going up or down

  private Timer timer;

  private float xloc = 0.0f;

  public BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
    // Create the root of the branch graph
    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    objTrans = new TransformGroup();
    objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    objRoot.addChild(objTrans);

    // Create a simple shape leaf node, add it to the scene graph.
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(0.25f);
    objTrans = new TransformGroup();
    objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
    pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    objTrans.setTransform(pos1);
    objTrans.addChild(sphere);
    objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
    BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        100.0);

    Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f);
    Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f);
    DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(light1Color,
        light1Direction);
    light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    objRoot.addChild(light1);

    // Set up the ambient light
    Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
    ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    objRoot.addChild(ambientLightNode);

    return objRoot;
  }

  public InteractiveAnimation() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse
        .getPreferredConfiguration();
    Canvas3D c = new Canvas3D(config);
    add("Center", c);
    c.addKeyListener(this);
    timer = new Timer(100, this);
    //timer.start();
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.add(go);
    add("North", p);
    go.addActionListener(this);
    go.addKeyListener(this);
    // Create a simple scene and attach it to the virtual universe
    BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();

    SimpleUniverse u = new SimpleUniverse(c);
    u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    u.addBranchGraph(scene);
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //Invoked when a key has been pressed.
    if (e.getKeyChar() == 's') {
      xloc = xloc + .1f;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
      xloc = xloc - .1f;
    }
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // Invoked when a key has been released.
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //Invoked when a key has been typed.
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // start timer when button is pressed
    if (e.getSource() == go) {
      if (!timer.isRunning()) {
        timer.start();
      }
    } else {
      height += .1 * sign;
      if (Math.abs(height * 2) >= 1)
        sign = -1.0f * sign;
      if (height < -0.4f) {
        trans.setScale(new Vector3d(1.0, .8, 1.0));
      } else {
        trans.setScale(new Vector3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
      }
      trans.setTranslation(new Vector3f(xloc, height, 0.0f));
      objTrans.setTransform(trans);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program Started");
    InteractiveAnimation bb = new InteractiveAnimation();
    bb.addKeyListener(bb);
    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame(bb, 256, 256);
  }
}
```

When I execute this, I get the following exception stack trace :-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
    at InteractiveAnimation.(InteractiveAnimation.java:84)
    at InteractiveAnimation.main(InteractiveAnimation.java:143)

What should I do to run this program ?

Comment: Have you installed Java3D properly? That is, is there a `Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.1` directory? The `bin` subdirectory there should contain 4 DLL files...

Comment: You can answer your own question. Maybe it will be helpful for others, if it was something special that is not already covered by other answers.

Comment: Actually, I just installed Java 3D, rather than using and managing jars and DLLs. Worked for me.

Comment: @Marco13 The very latest version of Java 3D is the version 1.6 pre 11 (in September 2014). Java 3D 1.5.1 is outdated.

Comment: @gouessej The version number is not so significant here, because the question referred to "any" pre-jogamp Java3D version (and obviously, they are all "outdated"). While it's nice to see efforts of reviving Java3D, the forum posts do not sound like there is a real committment of maintaining Java3D in the jogamp team, or is there? (No public links talking about Java3D at http://jogamp.org/ - and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html or https://java3d.java.net contain no infos either...). Actually, found Java3D not bad, so would like to see a committment here

Comment: Harvey actively maintains Java 3D, he's preparing the final stable release, there have been already 11 pre-releases since 2012, he fixed numerous bugs with the help of the community, there is a real commitment but of course there are tons of scenegraph APIs based on JOGL, we can't favor one, there is no consensus in this subject. The version number is very significant because there is no need of setting java.library.path with Java 3D 1.6 and using obsolete unmaintained versions of Java 3D is a pure waste of time as they don't work under latest OS X versions.

Comment: @Marco13 Moreover, Oracle has no obligation of mentioning JogAmp's Java 3D Continuation but the only maintained version of Java 3D is (JogAmp's) Java 3D 1.6. There is a section in our wiki about Java 3D and as the public API hasn't changed, the numerous examples available online still work.

Comment: @gouessej To phrase it that way: The version number was not significant because he anyhow referred to one of the "old" versions where the path still had to be set - and in the end, this is only a setup issue, and not one of the API, so for *pure* learning purposes, using 1.5.x would be fine. But of course, a maintained version is better (particularly when the setup becomes easier and less OS specific), and it's good to hear that there's development again from jogamp: Thumbs up!

Comment: In my humble opinion, using obsolete versions of Java 3D isn't fine even for pure learning purposes because it leads to confusion, it's complicated to install and Harvey fixed some bugs that were there for several years, especially multi-threading bugs. Nevertheless, I admit that Java 3D is only in maintenance mode, no new feature will be implemented, it's not a secret but it doesn't mean that there is no commitment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install Java 3D (latest version), rather than placing jars.

Comment: Sorry but your comment isn't accurate enough and a bit misleading. What do you mean by "Install Java 3D"? The extension mechanism has been deprecated in Java 1.9 and will be removed later, there is no way of "installing" a Java library.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are completely wrong. Java 3D 1.3.1 is completely outdated and it is no longer necessary to deal manually with DLLs in the very latest version of Java 3D (1.6). I explain how to install it [here](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/).